# подсчёт суммы товара

Tags: c#

Как вывести на экран  буквенное значение, например, товара:

Например программа выводит: булка, (нажимаешь enter) хлеб, (нажимаешь enter) печенки, (нажимаешь enter) по отдельности на новой строке и в конце выводит сумму.

Что нужно добавить к коду?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bye the bread");
            double bread = 2.50;
            Console.WriteLine("bye the milk");
            double milk = 3.30;
            double sum = bread + milk;
            //väljastan konsoolile muutujate väärtused. + abil saan liita muutujad stringi
            Console.WriteLine("The sum of " + bread + " and " + milk + " is " + sum);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вставьте в код строку `Console.ReadLine();` там, где у Вас "(нажимаешь enter)"

Comment: Если вы хотели написать "купить" то нужно писать "buy"

Answer (score 2):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Dictionary<string,int> products = new Dictionary<string,int>(){
         {имя товара 1, цена товара 1},
         {имя товара 2, цена товара 2}
     }
     int sum = 0;
     foreach (var keyValue in products){
         Console.WriteLine($"Итог: {keyValue.Value}");
         Console.WriteLine($"{keyValue.Key} по цене {keyValue.Value}");             
         if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
             sum+= keyValue.Value;
     }

}
```

Comment: как добавить в код если пользователь, может выбирать, какой товар покупать а кой нет, 
например булку выбирает,  а хлеб нет

Comment: `if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)` тут проверяется, нажал юзер **Enter** или нет. Если нажал, то к сумме прибавиться стоимость ,а если нет то нет